# Converting Postgres Function to Impala UDF or a function in Spark

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, hiveql, impala

I have a postgres function that is called in a query. Its similar to this sample:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function(id integer, dt date, days int[], accts text[], flag boolean) RETURNS float[] AS $$
  DECLARE
    pt_dates date[];
    pt_amt integer[];
    amt float[];
  BEGIN
  if cleared then
      pt_dates := array(select dt from tabl);
      pt_amt := array(select amt from tab1);
      if array_upper(days, 1) is not null then
       for j in 1 .. array_upper(days, 1)
       loop
         amt+=amt;
       end loop;
      end if;
      return amt;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If I wish to convert this to in to the Data Lake Environment, which is the best way to do it? Impala UDF? or Spark UDF ? or Hive UDF? In Impala UDF, how do I access the impala database? if I write Spark UDF can I use it in the impala-shell?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot lot lot of questions in your 1 post. So i'll choose just the Spark related question.

You have this SQL query that represents the data processing you wish to perform.

Here is a general formula to do this with Spark:

1. Take some amount of data, move it to S3
2. Go into AWS EMR and create a new cluster
3. SSH into the master node, and run `pyspark` console
4. once it has started, you can read in your S3 data via `rdd = sc.readText("s3://path/to/your/s3/buckets/")`
5. apply a schema to it with a `map` function `rdd2 = rdd.map(..add schema..)`
6. convert that `rdd2` into a `dataframe` and store that as a new var. `rdd2DF = rdd2.toDF()`
7. perform a `rdd2DF.registerTempTable('newTableName')` on that
8. write a SQL query and store the result: `output = sqlContext.sql("SELECT a,b,c FROM newTableName")`
9. show the output: `output.show()`

Now i know this is literally too high level to be a specific answer to your question, but everything i just said is **very google'able**.

And this is an example of a separated Compute and Storage scenario leveraging EMR with Spark and SparkSQL to process a lot of data with SQL queries.